# ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine after 1 message Python

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, server

After sending 1 message and getting the appropriate response, my client gives me an error saying the connection was aborted. The full error is:

Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\crayz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 973, in _bootstrap_inner
self.run()

File "C:\Users\crayz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 910, in run
self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)

File "D:\Coding Projects\Pandas\client.py", line 15, in recieve
received = sock.recv(1024).decode("UTF-8")
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine

server.py

```
import socketserver

class TCPHandler(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        # self.request is the TCP socket connected to the client
        self.data = self.request.recv(1024).strip()
        print(self.data.decode("UTF-8"))
        # just send back the same data
        self.request.sendall(self.data)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    HOST, PORT = "localhost", 9999
    # Create the server, binding to localhost on port 9999
    with socketserver.TCPServer((HOST, PORT), TCPHandler) as server:
        # Activate the server; this will keep running until you
        # interrupt the program with Ctrl-C
        server.serve_forever()
```

client.py

```
import socket
import sys
import threading
HOST, PORT = "localhost", 9999
user = input("Enter your username:\n")

# Create a socket (SOCK_STREAM means a TCP socket)
 
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect((HOST, PORT))
#make the recieve function
def recieve():
    #always check for new data
    while True:
        received = sock.recv(1024).decode("UTF-8")
        #check if the data is not empty
        if not received == '':
            #print the data
            print(received)
def sendmessage():  
    #always be checking if their is input
    while True:
        #get input
        data = input()
        #send the input
        sock.sendall(bytes(user + ": " + data + "\n", "utf-8"))
    
#start the threads
recieveThread = threading.Thread(target=recieve)
recieveThread.start()
sendThread = threading.Thread(target=sendmessage)
sendThread.start()
```